# Can not get Mongo 2d spatial query to return over 100 results

Tags: mongodb

By default a Mongo count() query on a 2d index returns at most 100 results.  I would like to count() the entire result set.  According to the count documentation, I can use **limit()** to bypass this constraint, but this does not work for me.  [MongoDB count.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)

I have tried setting a limit to 0 (unlimited) or 1000, but I always get back 100:

```
db.things.find({loc: { '$near': [ -122.43, 37.79 ],'$maxDistance': 0.12}}).limit(10000).count()
db.things.find({loc: { '$near': [ -122.43, 37.79 ],'$maxDistance': 0.12}}).limit(0).count()
```

I can do a find() and set a high limit and count the result set myself, but that seems like an inefficient approach and requires much more memory.  I also am arbitrarily setting another limit.

```
db.things.find({loc: { '$near': [ -122.43, 37.79 ],'$maxDistance': 0.12}}).limit(10000)

// In JS
thingsResult.length > 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime before I also  face similar problem , after searching I came to know it's a bug which is already locked in [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-856).

Try using below query , it returns all documents

```
cordinate = [ -122.43, 37.79 ];
maxDistance = 0.12 ;

db.location.find({"position" : {"$within" : 
                                      {"$center" : [cordinate , maxDistance ]}
                                }
                  });
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  i ended up using [$geoWithin] as $within has been deprecated (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin)